# Проблема с двумя dialog components в vuetify на странице

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vuetify

У меня есть два *dialog components* на странице, реализованных в **vuetify**. Когда я активирую любой из них, все они активируются одновременно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы они активировались отдельно?

Примечание: шаблон и скрипт не менялись, просто скопированы из vuetify.

Comment: На этом сайте задают вопросы на русском языке. Переведите вопрос нажав "Править".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверь v-model у диалоговых окон, они должны привязываться к разным переменным. Скорее всего у тебя окна привязаны к одной переменной, поэтому они открываются одновременно.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-btn @click="dialog1 = true">Открыть диалоговое окно 1</v-btn>
        <v-btn @click="dialog2 = true">Открыть диалоговое окно 2</v-btn>

        <v-dialog v-model="dialog1">Диалоговое окно 1</v-dialog>
        <v-dialog v-model="dialog2">Диалоговое окно 2</v-dialog>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            dialog1: false,
            dialog2: false,
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало!